# Adding Boolean field to a view

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that is being used to export data from my database to a 3rd party system, I have been asked to add a Boolean flag to the view that can be updated if the record has been exported to the other system. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: A view does not store data so you must add the flag column to one of the underlying tables and expose the column via the view.  If you can't change the existing table schema, you could create another table that stores the flag along with the primary key of the related table and join to that table in the view.

Comment: Suspected as much but it was worth asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need a column to say when is true or false.
You can change the schema view or the query that run against the view.

Just use a `case` clause

```
select *, case flag_column when 1 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as boolean_column from view
```

I suppose that is what you will need